# Which hadith/verse describe that Allah waits a period of time before punishing an oppressor, and the oppressor starts thinking he's invincible?

Tags: quran, hadith, reference-request

Can someone tell me the hadith book and hadith number being referred to [here in this video](https://youtu.be/FzR_03N8fqU?t=290)?

It is something like an oppressor keeps oppressing without being taken to task, and starts thinking that he is invincible, and then a time comes when Allah decides to punish him, and then there is no way he can escape His punishment.

If this hadith is not from sahih bukhari or sahih muslim and there is any doubt in it being non-authentic, do you know any authentic hadith/Quranic verse which gives the same lesson?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> إن الله ليملي للظالم حتى إذا أخذه لم يفلته
>
> Allah gives respite to the oppressor, but when He takes him over, He never releases him
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:4686) and [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2583)</sup>

Comment: JazakAllah Khair